# How to compare current width in css using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am currently trying to learn how to make a responsive MENU using HTML, CSS, JAVA. I want to shrink my menu when it is scrolled down within the max and specific width that i want to, but seems like my java code cant compare the current width of my web and the specific width that i want to compare. If the width is 830 bellow, I want the height of my menu to be 120 when when scrolled up and 60 when scrolled down.
And if the width is 830 higher, I want the height of my menu to be 400px when scrolled down and 60px when up. So here is my code for java.

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
var x, y;/*error here*/
x = document.getElementsByTagName('body').style.width(value);/*error  here*/
y = 830;/*error  here*/

function scrollFunction() {
  If ( x <= y)/*error  here*/
  {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) 
      {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "60px";   
      } 
    else 
      {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "400px";
      }
  }
  else
  {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) 
    {
      document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "60px";  
    } 
    else 
    {
      document.getElementById("menu").style.height = "120px";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong here so I assume you are a absolute newbie. First of all, to make a responsive menu, use CSS media queries instead of JavaScript (no, what you have written is not java). Second, there are no errors in places where you said there are errors except for the ones in which you capitalized the `if` keyword and called a `width` method which does not exist (use the `width` property instead to get width of an element). Third, you are using the `scrollTop` property which means how many pixels the user has scrolled which just doesn't make sense here.

Comment: use `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth`

Comment: Can you show me how I can compare the current width of my body tag and specific width that i want to compare. Forgive me i am indeed a newbie as u said I just started learning last week from scratch.